# Calculate if cannon with limited rotation angles can do fire in 3D space

Tags: math, 3d, linear-algebra, game-development

I want to create a game where it can be a lot of different cannons what will have different limit of fire angle (vertical and horizontal).

I found this formula to calculate angle between cannon and enemy position depend on cannon forward look vector in 2D:

```
float cannon_limit_angle = Math.PI * 0.5;

//the vectors 2d

vec2 cannon_pos = vec2(1,3);
vec2 cannon_facing = vec2(1,1);
vec2 enemy_pos = vec2(3,2);

//normalized vectors

vec2 cannon_facing_n = normalize(guard_facing);
vec2 enemy_to_cannon = normalize(hero_pos - guard_pos);

// calculating the angle

float angle = acos(dot(cannon_facing_n, enemy_to_cannon));

if (angle < cannon_limit_angle * 0.5) {
// Enemy inside limit angle
}
```

Now I am wondering how can I achieve this in 3D space?
I need the limits in horizontal and vertical axes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your code works in 2D it will work in 3D space as well,
since [image: dot(a,b)=|a|*|b|*cos(theta)] is valid in the 3D space. It works in 2D space as a particular case.

You could also simplify, by giving the cosine of the angle instead  of the angle itself, then you don't have to calculate the `acos` of the value, and you reduce your test to a  correlation threshold.